# MongoLab addon PHP app hosted on heroku

Tags: php, heroku, mlab

I've a PHP app to be hosted on heroku. The basic functionality of the app is to collect some data from users (through browsers) & store those in a database (since this is a PHP app, the database modifications must be made through PHP only). Now I've enabled the MongoLab addon from heroku control panel & created database, user, & sample collection into that database. I've deployed my code to heroku via git. Following is the content of a file **db.php** located inside the root folder of the app

```
<?php
 try {
   $user = 'my user name';
   $pass = 'my password';
   $app = 'my app name';
   $col = 'sample collection';
   echo 'connecting ...';
   $connection = new Mongo('mongodb://'.$user.':'.$pass.'@ds034512.mongolab.com:34512/'.$app);
   echo 'connected';
   $database   = $connection->selectDB($app);
   $collection = $database->selectCollection($col);
  }
  catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
   die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
  }
?>
```

now whenever I'm trying to execute the file on the heroku server itself (by caling the url **http://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/db.php** from my local browser) it's showing

> "**connecting ...**" & in the console there is an error message **"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/db.php"**

Can anyone suggest me any idea on how this database integration be done for apps hosted on heroku ?

Comment: Have you been able to connect to it via the shell? http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the mongodb driver. This gist has all the instructions.

https://gist.github.com/1288447